# Set theory in which it's possible for a function to be a member of its own domain

Tags: set-theory

In ZF set theory it's impossible to have a function $f: A \to B$ such that $f \in A$. Are there alternative set theories in which this is possible? Perhaps by allowing $A$ to be a proper class? Or is there an alternative way of thinking of functions (non set-theoretically) that would make this possible?

Comment: You "only" have to drop the Axiom of Regularity / Foundation, I suppose.

Comment: There are certainly set theories without regularity/foundation; besides $\mathsf{ZF(C)-Found}$ (possibly + antifoundation axioms) itself, there are also fundamentally different set theories like $\mathsf{NFU}$ or $\mathsf{GPK_\infty^+}$. That said, note that in many cases we can avoid the ill-foundedness in a natural way. For example, suppose we intuitively have a collection $F$ of functions $F\rightarrow F$. We can think of this instead as a set equipped with a *binary* function (basically $f*g=f(g)$). And this idea (if in reverse) is broadly useful - e.g. it's how you prove Cayley's theorem.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I'm not sure I understand the binary function idea. What is the domain of $*$? The product of a collection $F$ of functions mapping $F$ into itself? But then we are back to the problem we started with.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Right. I wonder, do you know a simple way of illustrating how costly dropping Regularity would be?

Comment: @aduh The idea is that anytime you have a situation which you think of as a set $F$ of functions each acting on $F$, you can instead model that same situation as just a binary operation on a set $A$; intuitively $A$ is just $F$, but all of this is happening "pre-formally," we're just trying to choose an approach to capturing the idea we have in mind. The latter avoids the "loopiness" of the former, and so there's no difficulty in implementing the latter in $\mathsf{ZF(C)}$.

Comment: Here's a way to make this precise. Working in the theory $\mathsf{ZF-Reg+AFA}$ (where $\mathsf{AFA}$ is a particular antifoundation axiom - ignore the details for now), we can show that if $F$ is a set of functions $F\rightarrow F$, there is an $A$ and a binary function $*$ on $A$ **which are each in the well-founded part of the universe** such that $(A,*)$ is isomorphic to $(F,\circ)$. So in a precise sense we can faithfully model an ill-founded situation in a well-founded way.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thanks, that's really interesting. Do you have a reference? Or is that an easy result once I know what AFA is?

Comment: @aduh It's an easy result. The key point is that in $\mathsf{AFA}$, every set is in bijection with some well-founded set. So just pick some bijection $i:F\rightarrow A$ with $A\in\mathsf{WF}$, and define $*$ appropriately.

Comment: This really depends on how you code stuff into sets.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks, can you elaborate?

Comment: Prof. K. Kunen uses ZF$^-$ for ZF minus Foundation.  In ZF we can find class-models that   satisfy ZF$^-$ but violate Foundation . In these models $\in$ is interpreted as a different relation than usual...  And in ZF$^-$ we have the class WF of well-founded sets satisfying ZF.... So if ZF$^-$ is consistent then it cannot prove nor rFoundation.

Answer (score 1):

If you delete Foundation (Regularity) then it is consistent to have some $x=\{x\}.$ Then for $f=id_x$ we have $$f=\{(y,y):y\in x\}=\{(x,x)\}=\{\{x\},\{x,x\}\}=\{\{x\}\}=\{x\}=x\in x=dom (f).$$